# Control mouse scroll step

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like my ReactJS application to scroll to screen height at once with each mouse scroll step. How can I set the mouse scroll step manually?
Otherwise, if this is not possible. I would like to detect the user's mouse step regardless of their device and browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your code, so that makes it hard to provide a correct implementation. But maybe you can use something like this:

```
const content = document.getElementById("content");
content.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let deltaY = event.deltaY;
    content.scrollTop += deltaY / n;
});
```

event.preventDefault is pretty straight forward, it prevents the default settings.
event.deltaY gives the current scrolling speed. If n is larger it will decrease the scrolling speed, if it is smaller it will increase the scrolling speed.
With content.scrollTop you can set the new adjusted speed.

I don't know if this is what your looking for, hope it helps.

Comment: I don't provide code because I don't have code where I'm trying to solve this issue. The bottom line is to simply control how many pixels to scroll with one action of the mouse wheel.

Comment: Alright, but this solution works then right?

Comment: Your solution didn't help directly, but gave me the right idea. I figured out how to find out the step of one mouse action and implemented the solution based on this